# Fixing a Cut PSU Wire

Tags: motherboard, power

Whilst replacing my PSU I had to cut a few cable ties and accidentaly cut into the cable that connects the power button to the motherboard. Is it possible to solder iron the cables and it work? Or do I need to replace that cable? If so, what is it called so I can order one?

[image: (see img: http://imgur.com/7eP25fW)]

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a picture? you may be able to temp fix it or solder on a new wire.

Comment: Unfortunately due to weird criteria on SE - you have to have a certain amount of rep to add img :( it isn't fully cut, about half of it is cut on the side closest to the power button (sorry for not being able to just show you)

Comment: StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: That looks like a lot of cables to fix. How handy are you with a soldering iron?

Comment: I would buy a new cable.

Comment: what are the names of the cable? I think it would be easier to just buy and replace as I have no prior soldering iron experience haha

Comment: Check with tech support at the computer manufacturer.  They might have a replacement cable, or they can tell you exactly what to buy.  Soldering those kinds of cables can get messy (and then you need to re-insulate the area).  You could buy a couple of cable connectors, inter-connect those, and fasten them on each side of the cut.  However, that's likely to be more expensive and more work that buying a new cable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a modular PSU cable, then the manufacturer won't help.  The wires are soldered to the PSU board, and breaking the case seal voids the warranty and safety approvals.

It's not obvious how many wires you cut in that cable bundle.

The keyword is *"splice"*.  You need to splice the cut wires.
There are solderless connectors for splicing wires (but you would need a crimp tool). https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=splice+wire+connectors&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

A butt-splice connector would probably work best.

[image]

Choose one for the appropriate wire gauge/size.
[image]

[How to use butt-splice connector](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+use+butt-splice+connector&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)